# How can I create a instance like objective-c do?

Tags: swift, singleton-methods

Usually, I create a class's instance like this:

The Parent class:

```
@interface baseClass  
+ (instancetype)task;  
@end  
@implement baseClass  
+ (instancetype)task {  
    return [[[self class] alloc] init];  
}  
@end
```

and then in children class:

```
@interface childClass : baseClass  
@end  
@implement childClass  
@end
```

Finally, I can create a instance using:

```
childClass *pChild = [childClass task];
```

How could I implement this feature by using the Swift programming language?

In another word, how could I implement the `[[[self class] alloc] init]` in swift way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a bit insecure about you tagged your question as a *singleton* but basically the code you presented has nothing to do with singletons at all, so I tried to mimic your original classes and show a few options here.

these are written in *Swift 2.2*.

---

## case #1

that works flawlessly initially:

```
class BaseClass {

    class func task() -> BaseClass {
        return BaseClass()
    }

    // ...

}

class ChildClass : BaseClass {

    override class func task() -> ChildClass {
        return ChildClass()
    }

    // ...

}
```

then you would be able to get instances like this:

```
let bTask: BaseClass = BaseClass.task()
let cTask: ChildClass = ChildClass.task()
```

---

## case #2

you can also do something like this, if such thing looks more reasonable for you:

```
class BaseClass {
    
    class var task: AnyObject {
        get {
            return self.init()
        }
    }
    
    required init() {
        
    }
    
    // ...

}

class ChildClass : BaseClass {
    
    // ...

}
```

then you can instantiate your classes like:

```
let bTask: BaseClass = BaseClass.task as! BaseClass
let cTask: ChildClass = ChildClass.task as! ChildClass
```

---

## case #3

here is an other option for you too, if you are not happy with any of the ideas above:

```
class BaseClass {
    
    class func task() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }
    
    required init() {
        
    }
    
    // ...

}

class ChildClass : BaseClass {
    
    // ...

}
```

the instantiation is similar to the first case:

```
let bTask: BaseClass = BaseClass.task()
let cTask: ChildClass = ChildClass.task()
```

---

*NOTE: you may need to refine the chosen concept for your final code if you want to deal with real singletons, these examples are not perfectly worked out as I mentioned at the beginning but they show you a few options you can have and you can use as template.*

Comment: Thanks a lot! The **Case #3** is works for me. Thanks a again! I think about that the Swift has many misunderstand syntax. So I had been confusing in many times.

Comment: @imeteora, not a problem, I will leave the other two options here as well; who knows, maybe someone could use them in future.

Answer (score 0):

If AClass not subclass of `NSObject`

```
class AClass {
    required init() {

    }
    class func task() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }
}

class BClass : AClass {

}

let x = BClass.task()
```

You need implement `init()` and add `required` keyword, because if want subclass `BClass` or other class which inherited from `AClass` can use `task`, you have to ensure subclass can use `init()`;

Otherwise you need add `final` keyword:

```
final class AClass {
    init() {

    }
    class func task() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }
}
```

but i think you don't need it.

And if AClass is inherited from `NSObject`, you need override `init()` and add `required` too:

```
class AClass : NSObject {
    required override init() {

    }
    class func task() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }
}

class BClass : AClass {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

At Swift (add class before every func):

```
class baseClass: NSObject {
    class func task() {

    }
}

class childClass: baseClass {

}

let test = childClass.task()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class var sharedInstance :CommonUtil {
    struct Singleton {
        static let instance = CommonUtil()
    }

    return Singleton.instance
}
```

Comment: the OP is not dealing with singletons here.